# g++ - Terminal Memory Allocation

Tags: memory, ubuntu, terminal, g++

I've compiled and am currently running a program with g++. I expect that it's going to take a while to run but I'm hoping I might be able to speed it up. I'm currently using Ubuntu. Checking the system monitor I found the terminal I'm running the program from. While it certainly is using a chunk of memory, there's far more memory available. Is there some sort of command for the terminal or something that will allow me to allocate more memory to the program so it will run a bit faster? Or a command for g++? Or just something to put in the C++ code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving the program more memory will not make it run faster; it will ask for more memory from the operating system as needed. You're thinking of the behavior of languages with garbage collection, like Java. Normal C++ programs don't include a garbage collector, and thus won't run any faster with a larger heap.

Comment: I thought this might also be the case. Thanks then.